# 404 error after update-spsolution with site definition

Tags: 2010, site-definition

i ran a upate-spsolution to update a site defintion and now any existing sites created from that site definition throws back a 404 error.  Strangely any new sites i create using the site definition are just fine.  The site definition contains a reference to a custom master page.  Any ideas?

Comment: as far as I knew, you can't update site definitions however you can save a site created by a site definition as a template after making changes, correct me if am wrong

Comment: Updating Site Definitions is unsupported. With that said, could you provide some more information about the changes you have done to the Site Definition?